# Including c files in .msg files (Veins)

Tags: c, omnet++, veins

I'm  trying to implement a BSM in Veins 4.4. In order to reach this purpose I would like to import my libasn which are C files (.c and .h ) in the WaveShortMessage.msg in order to populate the BSM.

I tried to import them as follows:

1. `#include "veins/asn/BasicSafetyMessage.h"`
2. `#include <veins/asn/BasicSafetyMessage.h>`

3.

```
extern "C" {
   #include "veins/asn/BasicSafetyMessage.h"
};
```

4.

```
    #ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C" {
    #endif
    #include "veins/asn/BasicSafetyMessage.h"
    #ifdef __cplusplus
    }
    #endif
```

but it doesn't work. It always returns an error.

Could you suggest the right way to do it? Thanks a lot

Comment: _It always returns an error_: good to know, but which error ??

Comment: In case 1,2 and 4 "Error: syntax error, unexpected BIN_XOR, expecting $end"; in case 3 "Error: syntax error, unexpected NAME, expecting $end".

Comment: sorry case 2 is #include <veins/asn/BasicSafetyMessage.h>

Comment: Seems like the file is included just fine, as would be expected if the compiler knows or is told where to look for it. The syntax error is just that - an error of syntax, as opposed to an error of being unable to find and include a file. These can occur (amongst other times) when incompatible versions of libraries are mixed or when files are included in the wrong order.

Comment: In both cases? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a C or C++ code in the message's definition in `OMNeT++` is described in details in [OMNeT++ Simulation Manual, chapter 6.5](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:msg-defs:cplusplus-blocks). 
You should use `cplusplus` keyword, an example for C code in `BasicSafetyMessage.h`:

```
cplusplus {{
extern "C" {
#include "veins/asn/BasicSafetyMessage.h"
};
}}
```

Comment: I have edited my answer and added `extern "C"`. The other way is to add `extern "C"` in your file `BasicSafetyMessage.h`.